# Moving values but preserving order in a Python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and want to 'move' its values so it changes into

```
a=[2,3,4,5,1]
```

and the next step

```
a=[3,4,5,1,2]
```

Is there a built-in function in Python to do that?

Or is there a shorter or nicer way than

```
b=[a[-1]]; b.extend(a[:-1]); a=b
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a.append(a.pop(0))
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

This is expensive, though, as it has to shift the contents of the entire list, which is O(n).  A better choice may be to use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) if it is available in your version of Python, which allow objects to be inserted and removed from either end in approximately O(1) time:

```
>>> a = collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.rotate(-1)
>>> a
deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
```

Note also that both these solutions involve changing the original sequence object, whereas yours creates a new list and assigns it to `a`.  So if we did:

```
>>> c = a
>>> # rotate a
```

With your method, `c` would continue to refer to the original, unrotated list, and with my methods, it will refer to the updated, *rotated* list/deque.