# Python list rotation

Tags: python, list, rotation

I'd like to rotate a Python list by an arbitrary number of items to the right or left (the latter using a negative argument).

Something like this:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l.rotate(0)
[1,2,3,4]
>>> l.rotate(1)
[4,1,2,3]
>>> l.rotate(-1)
[2,3,4,1]
>>> l.rotate(4)
[1,2,3,4]
```

How might this be done?

Comment: I don't use Python, but if you have a push/pop method, you can l.push(l.pop()). Then for loop it. That would cover moving forward.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python) help?

Comment: This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212025/moving-values-in-a-list-in-python

Comment: Thanks for the links to other questions.  I tried searching Google and SO for `python list rotation` and didn't find any of those.  This question may serve as a landing page for people thinking of 'rotating' rather than 'shifting'.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: both show up in the first page of SO search results for "python list rotate".  Need to use shorter forms of the words, I think. ;-)

Comment: @DSM, I guess I expected SO's search stemming to be better than that.  I'll delete this question.

Comment: The other question is specifically about efficiency; this one may cover slightly different ground.

Comment: Deletion seems like overkill -- never hurts to have another key in the dict! -- although this question hasn't hit different ground yet (each answer has a variant in the other questions).

Comment: This "duplicate", and the answers here were more useful than the original.  Thanks!

Comment: For a constant space solution try, `l.insert(0, l.pop(-1))` in a for loop of n times (number of rotate). For negative rotations, `l.append(l.pop(0))` might be useful.

Answer (score 207):

```
def rotate(l, n):
    return l[-n:] + l[:-n]
```

More conventional direction:

```
def rotate(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]
```

Example:

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

rotate(example_list, 2)
# [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

The arguments to `rotate` are a list and an integer denoting the shift. The function creates two new lists using [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/553404) and returns the concatenatenation of these lists. The `rotate` function does not modify the input list.

Comment: Nice and simple.  It rotates the opposite direction to that specified in the question though.

Comment: @S.Lott: One could argue that the OP's direction is backwards in his example. Most Python tutorials on slice idiom with a list rotation has the sign convention the same direction as Mr E first rotation function...

Comment: I'd add `n = n % len(n)` to make this work for `n > len(n)`.

Comment: Is there a way to this without `return` ? I tried `l=l[n:] + l[:n]` but when I try to return a `l` I get the original.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The function doesn't modify the input parameter, it returns a new list. Probably best to ask a new question about your issue.

Comment: @user1071136 I think you mean `n = n % len(l)`.

Answer (score 129):

If applicable, you could use `collections.deque` as a solution:

```
import collections

d = collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5])
d.rotate(3)

print d
>>> deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2])
```

As a bonus, I'd expect it to be faster than in-built list.

Comment: For future readers: `collections.deque rotate()` is faster than slicing according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: shouldn't it be mentioned that collections is rotating to the left by default?

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik deque.rotate rotates to the right https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate

Answer (score 28):

The following function will rotate the list `l`, `x` spaces to the right:

```
def rotate(l, x):
  return l[-x:] + l[:-x]
```

Note that this will only return the original list if `x` is outside the range `[-len(l), len(l)]`.  To make it work for all values of `x`, use:

```
def rotate(li, x):
  return li[-x % len(li):] + li[:-x % len(li)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to this without `return` ? I tried `l=l[n:] + l[:n]` but when I try to return a `l` I get the original.

Comment: @GinKin Why without a return?  That's how you return things from a function.  I mean, you could use a lambda, but that just makes the return implicit.

Comment: I want to make it 'in place' so it won't return anything and if I'll type `>>> l` after running the function I'll get a the rotated list, not the original.

Comment: @GinKin Instead of `return ...` you can say `l[:] = ...` and it will do it in place.  I don't recommend this, though.

Comment: Why not ? (extra words for minimum amount to comment)

Comment: @GinKin Functions in Python are generally expected to be side-effect free; normally you would only change one of the parameters if it was the first (`self`) argument to a method.  It's just a convention, though.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> l[1:]+l[:1]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> l[2:]+l[:2]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
>>> l[-1:]+l[:-1]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

A general rotate `n` to the left (positive y in the call to `rotate`) or right (negative y) then:

```
def rotate(l, y=1):
   if len(l) == 0:
      return l
   y = y % len(l)    # Why? this works for negative y

   return l[y:] + l[:y]
```

If you want the direction of rotation to be the same as your example, just negate `y` in rotate.

```
def rotate(l, y=1):
   if len(l) == 0:
      return l
   y = -y % len(l)     # flip rotation direction

   return l[y:] + l[:y]
```