# Python Array Rotation

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, rotation, swap

So I am implementing a block swap algorithm in python.

The algorithm I am following is this:

Initialize A = arr[0..d-1] and B = arr[d..n-1]
1) Do following until size of A is equal to size of B

a)  If A is shorter, divide B into Bl and Br such that Br is of same 
       length as A. Swap A and Br to change ABlBr into BrBlA. Now A
       is at its final place, so recur on pieces of B.

b)  If A is longer, divide A into Al and Ar such that Al is of same 
       length as B Swap Al and B to change AlArB into BArAl. Now B
       is at its final place, so recur on pieces of A.

2)  Finally when A and B are of equal size, block swap them.

The same algorithm has been implemented in C on this website - [Array Rotation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/block-swap-algorithm-for-array-rotation/)

My python code for the same is

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

x = 2

n = len(a)


def rotate(a,x):
    n = len(a)

    if x == 0 or x == n:
        return a

    if x == n -x:
        print(a)
        for i in range(x):
            a[i], a[(i-x+n) % n] = a[(i-x+n) % n], a[i]
        print(a)
        return a

    if x < n-x:
        print(a)
        for i in range(x):
            a[i], a[(i-x+n) % n] = a[(i-x+n) % n], a[i]
        print(a)
        rotate(a[:n-x],x)
    else:
        print(a)
        for i in range(n-x):
            a[i], a[(i-(n-x) + n) % n] = a[(i-(n-x) + n) % n] , a[i]
        print(a)
        rotate(a[n-x:], n-x)

rotate(a,x)
print(a)
```

I am getting the right values at each stage but the recursive function call is not returning the expected result and I cannot seem to understand the cause. Can someone explain whats wrong with my recursion ? and what can be the possible alternative.

Answer (score 32):

You can rotate a list in place in Python by using a [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d=deque([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> d
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> d.rotate(2)
>>> d
deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])
>>> d.rotate(-2)
>>> d
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Or with list slices:

```
>>> li=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> li[2:]+li[:2]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
>>> li[-2:]+li[:-2]
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Note that the sign convention is opposite with deque.rotate vs slices.

If you want a function that has the same sign convention:

```
def rotate(l, y=1):
   if len(l) == 0:
      return l
   y = -y % len(l)     # flip rotation direction
   return l[y:] + l[:y]

>>> rotate([1,2,3,4,5],2)
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
>>> rotate([1,2,3,4,5],-22)
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
>>> rotate('abcdefg',3)
'efgabcd'
```

---

For numpy, just use [np.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

```
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.roll(a, 1)
array([9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> np.roll(a, -1)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

Or you can use a numpy version of the same `rotate` above (again noting the difference in sign vs `np.roll`):

```
def rotate(a,n=1):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return a
    n = -n % len(a)     # flip rotation direction
    return np.concatenate((a[n:],a[:n]))
```

Comment: there are a lot of python i could use as you suggested. However it was given to me as a challenge that I had to implement without using the inhouse method. If you could suggest a modification in the above code, it would be great

Comment: @dawg If li is a numpy.array, the addition does not concatenate both arrays but do an item by item addition instead. How can I do your rotate operation with a numpy array ?

Comment: @dawg I like your answer a lot, I just wish I saw this answer earlier, in the meantime, I did this: `np.concatenate((a[n:],a[:n]))`

Comment: @dawg According to IPython %timeit, `np.concatenate( ( a[n:], a[:n] ) )` seems 10 times faster :)

Comment: @SebMa: `np.concatenate( ( a[n:], a[:n] ) )` is indeed faster. It does slows down for larger arrays. Similar to the Python answer I gave I suppose. Thanks! I will add that.

Comment: List slicing method will fail. When rotation value is more than the len of the list

Answer (score 21):

A simple and shorthand syntax for array rotation in Python is

```
arr = arr[numOfRotations:]+arr[:numOfRotations]
```

Example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
rotations = 4
then 

arr = arr[4:]+arr[:4]
```

gives us

[5,1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 14):

I found a problem that I needed Right and Left rotations for big values of k (where k is number of rotations), so, I implemented the following functions for any size of k.

**Right Circular Rotation** (left to the right: 1234 -> 4123):

```
def right_rotation(a, k):
   # if the size of k > len(a), rotate only necessary with
   # module of the division
   rotations = k % len(a)
   return a[-rotations:] + a[:-rotations]
```

**Left Circular Rotation** (right to the left: 1234 -> 2341):

```
def left_rotation(a, k):
   # if the size of k > len(a), rotate only necessary with
   # module of the division
   rotations = k % len(a)
   return a[rotations:] + a[:rotations]
```

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46846544/7468664
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9457923/7468664

Answer (score 5):

Do you actually need to implement the block swap or are you just looking to rotate the array? In python you can do CW and CWW rotations using

```
zip(*arr[::-1])
```

and

```
zip(*arr)[::-1]
```

Comment: Can you explain this more?

Comment: @LongHoang This answer doesn't actually answer the question, as it does clockwise and counterclockwise rotations on **2D arrays**.  I will likely delete this answer later today.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that when you pass a slice of a to your recursive call, you're not passing the same variable any more. Try passing a in its entirety and the upper / lower bounds of your slice as additional arguments to your function.

For instance consider this function:

```
def silly(z):
  z[0] = 2
```

I just tried the following:

```
>>> z = [9,9,9,9,9,9]
>>> silly(z)
>>> z
[2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
>>> silly(z[3:])
>>> z
[2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Where you can see the modification to the slice was not retained by the full array

Out of curiosity, what outputs do you get & what outputs do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for left rotation in python array

```
import copy
def leftRotate(arr,n) :
    _arr = copy.deepcopy(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)-n):
        arr[i] = arr[i+n]
    for j in range(n):
        arr[(len(arr)-n)+j] = _arr[j]

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
leftRotateby = 3
leftRotate(arr,leftRotateby)
print arr 
#output:: [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @Ângelo Polotto's answer is correct, this one doesn't work at edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Array Rotation:-

```
print("Right:1,Left:2")
op=int(input())
par=[1,2]
if op not in par:
   print("Invalid Input!!")
   
else:  
  arr=list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
  shift=int(input())
  if op ==1:
    right=arr[-shift:]+arr[:-shift]
    print(right)
  elif op==2:
    left=arr[shift:]+arr[:shift]  
    print(left)
```

Ouput:-`

```
Right:1,Left:2
1
12 45 78 91 72 64 62 43
2
[62, 43, 12, 45, 78, 91, 72, 64]`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not supposed to use deque or slicing:

```
def rotate(array: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
    # loop through the array from -k to array_size - k
    return [array[i] for i in range(-k, len(array) - k)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've used the method of swapping using a temporary variable to rotate an array. As an example, an array '**a**' of **size 5** is considered. Two variables **'j'** and **'i'** are used for outer and inner loop iterations respectively. **'c'** is the temporary variable. Initially, the 1st element in the array is swapped with the last element in the array i.e **a=[5,2,3,4,1]**. Then, the 2nd element is swapped with the current last element i.e in this case 2 and 1. At present, the array **'a'** would be **a=[5,1,3,4,2]**. This continues till it reaches the second last element in the array. Hence, if the size of the array is **n** (5 in this case), then **n-1** iterations are done to rotate the array. To enter the no of times the rotation must be done, m is given a value with which the outer loop is run by comparing it with the value of j.

**Note: The rotation of array is towards the left in this case**

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
n=len(a)
m=int(input('Enter the no of rotations:'))
j=0
while(j<m):
    i=0
    while(i<n):
        c=a[i]
        a[i]=a[n-1]
        a[n-1]=c
        i=i+1
    j=j+1
print(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def leftRotation():
    
    li = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

    d = int(input())
    ans = (li[d:]+li[0:d])

    for i in ans:
        print(i,end=' ')
    print()
    
leftRotation()
```

Comment: Could you explain what was wrong with the original code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the original code. I just wanted to share a different approach where I used slicing.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def rotLeft(a, d):
    lenght=len(a)
    for j in range(0,d):
     temp = a[0]
     
     for i in range(lenght-1):
        a[i] = a[i+1]
     a[lenght-1] = temp
    # Write your code here
    return a    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

    n = int(first_multiple_input[0])

    d = int(first_multiple_input[1])

    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = rotLeft(a, d)

    fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def rotate(nums=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k=3):
    i=0
    while i < k:
        pop_item = nums.pop()
        nums.insert(0, pop_item)
        i += 1

    return nums  # [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
def rotate(nums, k):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type k: int
    :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    result = []
    if len(nums) <= 1 : return nums
    if k > len(nums): k = K % len(nums)
    
    for i in range(k):
        result.insert(0,nums[-1])
        nums.pop()
    nums = result + nums
    return nums
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).