# How do I rotate a 2-dimensional array in Python or how can I get the result below?

Tags: python

```
I have Input: 
[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
[[1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
[[1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]
[[2, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0]]
[[1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1]]
[[0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0]]
[[0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2]]
[[1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1]] #Array

I want to output print on screen:
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2]]
[[2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
[[1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]
[[2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2]]
[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
[[1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1]]
[[0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
[[1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2]]
[[2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1]]

Ex:
A=[[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]],
[[1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]],
[[1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]]
```

### I want write code PYTHON to A[0][1] swap A[1][0], A[0][2] swap A[2][0] and A[1][2] swap A[2][1]

```
Output: 
A=[[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2]],
[[2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]],
[[1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]]
```

##  Please help me!!! Thank you all so much!!!

Comment: add: Use programming language Python3 (the pure version without using any external packages like numpy, pandas, pytorch,…) to write program.

Comment: Maybe you can take advantage from other answers like [Python Array Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350330/) or [Rotating a two-dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421337/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>> A=[[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]],
... [[1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]],
... [[1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]]

>>> transpose_data = map(list, zip(*A))
>>> for data in transpose_data:
...     print(data)
...
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2]]
[[2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
[[1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(A)
np.flip(np.rot90(A, axes=(0,1)), axis=0)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the article asking not to use an external library like numpy
Thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]],
[[1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]],
[[1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]]

rows = len(A)
cols = len(A[0])
B = []

for col in range(cols):
bb = []
for row in range(rows):
    bb.append(A[row][col])
B.append(bb)
```