# How can I move a item in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array -

```
['L', 'London', 'M', 'Moscow', 'NYC', 'Paris', 'nan']
```

I want 'nan' to be first, like so:

```
['nan', 'L', 'London', 'M', 'Moscow', 'NYC', 'Paris']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Array Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350330/python-array-rotation)

Comment: Is `nan` always last, or can it be anywhere?  In general this isn't an efficient operation in numpy.

Comment: It can be anyway. I modified Andrej's answer to find the location of the 'nan' then subtract it from the size of the array then shift it by that amount so the value 'nan'(or any I choose in the future) will always be first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `numpy`, you can use [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
a = np.array(['L', 'London', 'M', 'Moscow', 'NYC', 'Paris', 'nan'])

a = np.roll(a, 1)

print(a)
```

Prints:

```
['nan' 'L' 'London' 'M' 'Moscow' 'NYC' 'Paris']
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej! It worked.  I made a slight modification to find the location then shift by that amount regardless of the position of the value I want to roll -     locationOfNaN = np.where(a == 'nan')[0][0] #find location of value
    DistanceToRoll =  (len(a)) - (locationOfNaN)

then roll by DistanceToRoll to make it dynamic. Thank you.