# How to rotate an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an array in Python. I've read the following post [Python Array Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350330/python-array-rotation)

Where I found this little snippet of code

```
arr = arr[numOfRotations:]+arr[:numOfRotations]
```

I've tried to put this into the following function:

```
def solution(A, K):
    A = A[K:] + A[:K]
    print(A)
    return A
```

Where A is my array and K is the number of rotations. Only I get the following error, ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,).

I don't understand where I'm going wrong? Ideally I a solution that can solve this without using any Numpy inbuilt short cuts functions.

Cheers

Edit: This is the full program

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

def solution(A, K):
    A = A[K:]+A[:K]
    print(A)
    return A

solution(A, 2)
```

Comment: Could you show us how you are calling your method ? The code you provided work well for me using `solution([1,2,3], 1)`

Comment: Really these don't work??? Worked for me with `solution([1,2,3],1)` in test

Comment: So when I call it the same way you two did it works fine, but this method provides a list as the argument and not an array. Which seems to be the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `np.concatenate((A[K:],A[:K]))`
if A is an array,
you function works when `A` is `list`

Lest try to look at from your example

```py
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
K = 2
print(A[K:])
print(A[:K])
```

Will give you `[3 4 5]` and `[1 2]` .
in your code you are trying to add them using `+` sign.
Since the these two values are of different shapes you cant add them, hence you will get `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)`

The correct implementation for an array will be

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

def solution(A, K):
    A = np.concatenate((A[K:],A[:K]))
    print(A)
    return A
```