# Rotate the array to the right by k steps

Tags: python

Given an integer array nums, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.

Example:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3

Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

Explanation:

rotate 1 steps to the right: [7,1,2,3,4,5,6]

rotate 2 steps to the right: [6,7,1,2,3,4,5]

rotate 3 steps to the right: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

How to solve the task with O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity (if possible)?

P.S. I know solutions with O(kn) time complexity and O(1) space complexity only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Array Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350330/python-array-rotation)

Comment: You'll never get O(1) space complexity. O(n) is the minimum, since... the input takes up space. Unless you mean specifically auxiliary space that isn't the input.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: @CrazyChucky, ok, O(1) extra space

Comment: Please do not post your homeworks on SO.

Answer (score 0):

This is functionally correct but, as far as I can tell it's neither O(1) nor O(n) in terms of time complexity.

Why? O(1) depends on the input size but that's not relevant in this case. The time complexity is determined by *k*. That also applies to the O(n) definition.

If we ignore what might be happening "under the covers" it is O(1) in terms of [additional] space complexity.

```
def rotate(lst, k):
    for _ in range(k):
        lst.insert(0, lst.pop())
    return lst

print(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3))
```

If you were not concerned with additional space, you should be able to achieve O(1) time complexity with:

```
def rotate(lst, k):
    return lst[-k:] + lst[:k+1]
```

**Output (in both cases):**

```
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a single temporary variable to hold the value that is moving and run through the indexes from one target position to another (using modulo to wrap around the size of the list):

```
def rotInPlace(A,k):
    v,i = A[0],k
    for _ in A:
        v,A[i] = A[i],v
        i = (i+k)%len(A)
```

Output:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
k = 3

rotInPlace(nums,k)

print(nums)
# [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```