# How to rotate and print all the characters of a string in python3 starting from every character of the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example i have a string "mission", i want my program to print as below starting from the first letter.

mission
issoinm
ssionmi
sionmis
ionmiss
onmissi
nmissio

Answer (score 1):

This code would give the exact output you're expecting.

```
def rotate(lst, n):
    return lst[-n:] + lst[:-n]

s = 'mission'

for i in range(len(s)):
    print(rotate(s,-i), end=' ')
```

Output:

```
mission issionm ssionmi sionmis ionmiss onmissi nmissio
```

The function for rotation was borrowed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9457864/4565943).