# Shifting the elements of a list

Tags: python, list

```
L=["apple","banana","mango","kiwi"]
```

If the user enters a fruit, let's say banana, the output must be

```
["banana","mango","kiwi","apple"]
```

Should I use the back shifting principle?
Please help.

Comment: Try [`rotate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457832/python-list-rotation)

Comment: I want the fruit that is entered by the user to be the first element

Comment: With `L.index(e)` your are getting the position of the element `e` in your list. `L.index("banana")` gives you `1`.

Comment: You can use: `fruit = 'banana'; L[L.index(fruit):] + L[:L.index(fruit)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(["apple","banana","mango","kiwi"])
d.rotate(-list(d).index("banana"))
print(list(d))
```

Output:

```
['banana', 'mango', 'kiwi', 'apple']
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @SuprathaThinakaran glad to help!