# how to order a dictionary based on key by daywise in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, calendar, ordereddict

I had 2 list

```
daydate=['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

percentday=['0%', '17%', '27%', '11%', '7%', '19%', '19%']
```

i have converted into dictionary by doing

`daydic=dict(zip(daydate, percentday))`

the output is coming like

```
{'Monday': '17%', 'Tuesday': '27%', 'Friday': '19%', 'Wednesday': '11%', 'Thursday': '7%', 'Sunday': '0%', 'Saturday': '19%'}
```

i want to sort this dictionary like the order of elements in daywise like below

```
{'Sunday': '0%','Monday': '17%', 'Tuesday': '27%', 'Wednesday': '11%', 'Thursday': '7%', , 'Friday': '19%','Saturday': '19%'}
```

Help me

Comment: Dictionaries don't have a sorting. You can sort it when you print, by sorting the keys

Comment: @TomdeGeus: i want to sort by daywise,i.e., week day wise. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 6):

#### Dictionaries should not be considered ordered

They are, in fact, *insertion ordered* in Python 3.6+ (officially 3.7+), but even so you should *prefer* to use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for a robust ordered mapping.

In addition, you should never have to type days of the week manually, you can import from [`calendar.day_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name) and rotate via [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from calendar import day_name
from collections import deque, OrderedDict

daydate = deque(day_name)
daydate.rotate(1)

percentday = ['0%', '17%', '27%', '11%', '7%', '19%', '19%']

res = OrderedDict(zip(daydate, percentday))

OrderedDict([('Sunday', '0%'),
             ('Monday', '17%'),
             ('Tuesday', '27%'),
             ('Wednesday', '11%'),
             ('Thursday', '7%'),
             ('Friday', '19%'),
             ('Saturday', '19%')])
```

Answer (score 0):

As told, a dict is not ordered, but you can order before to convert to dict.

```
daydate=['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
percentday=['0%', '17%', '27%', '11%', '7%', '19%', '19%']
```

Sort by day, just rotate the zip:

```
dayzip = list(zip(daydate, percentday))
dayzip = dayzip[1-len(dayzip):] + dayzip[:1-len(dayzip)]
daydict = dict(dayzip)

#=> {'Sunday': '0%', 'Monday': '17%', 'Tuesday': '27%', 'Wednesday': '11%', 'Thursday': '7%', 'Friday': '19%', 'Saturday': '19%'}
```

To sort by percentage:

```
dayzip = list(zip(daydate, percentday))
dayzip.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[1][:-1]) )
daydict = dict(dayzip)


#=> [('Sunday', '0%'), ('Monday', '17%'), ('Tuesday', '27%'), ('Wednesday', '11%'), ('Thursday', '7%'), ('Friday', '19%'), ('Saturday', '19%')]
#=> {'Sunday': '0%', 'Thursday': '7%', 'Wednesday': '11%', 'Monday': '17%', 'Friday': '19%', 'Saturday': '19%', 'Tuesday': '27%'}
```

Comment: But OP wants to sort by day, *not* by value.

Comment: Oops! In case, rotate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457832/python-list-rotation. I''l edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
daydic={'Friday': '19%', 'Wednesday': '11%', 'Monday': '17%', 'Thursday': '7%', 'Saturday': '19%', 'Sunday': '0%', 'Tuesday': '27%'}
weeks=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
print(OrderedDict(sorted(daydic.items(),key =lambda x:weeks.index(x[0]))))
```

This will output as:

```
OrderedDict([('Sunday', '0%'), ('Monday', '17%'), ('Tuesday', '27%'), ('Wednesday', '11%'),
 ('Thursday', '7%'), ('Friday', '19%'), ('Saturday', '19%')])
```