# issues creating a list of integers with its start and stop point

Tags: python, list

I would like to create a list from 0 to 11 with starting point 6 and that runs all the range of numbers to obtain the following output:

```
[6,7,8,9,10,11,0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

I would like to know if there was an array creation routine to do so:
Something like:

```
range(start=7,stop=6,step=1)
```

Comment: Do you want a list, or a numpy array? They're not the same data type, so the best technique to make one may not be the best way to make the other.

Comment: Use arange followed by `np.roll`?

Comment: @Blckknght preferable a list

Comment: Given `range(start=7,stop=6,step=1)` how is it even obvious that the start is 0 and end is 11?

Comment: You can do rotation as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457832/python-list-rotation

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `start, end, mid = 0, 11, 6; [*range(mid, end+1), *range(start, mid)]` but without further clarification or examples, don't think much more can be said

Comment: @cs95 sorry,  I did not know how to express my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way to generate list would be like:

```
a = list(range(6, 12))+list(range(0, 6))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this fulfill your needs?

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.arange(12)
ar = np.roll(ar, 6)

# or np.roll(np.arange(12), 6)

print(ar)
```

Returns:

```
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an ordinary Python list, you can form it from two ascending 
lists like so:

```
>>> list(range(6, 12)) + list(range(6))
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```