# Generating all possible sets of 3 groups of 6 numbers chosen from the integers 1-18

Tags: python, set, combinations, permutation

Since the groups of 6 represent dice, the order of the integers in these groups does not matter. The order of the groups within each set does matter, but to check each one it would be simple to find the permutations of each set, which I can do.

Now, I've come up with a way to achieve all this, the problem is efficiency. I want to check each set but so far I've only come up with a way using:

```
for i in itertools.combinations(num, 6):
    W.append([i])
print(W)
print("Done building list of ",len(W)," possible dice.")
```

which gives me all possible dice of 6 numbers chosen from 18 integers where the order of the numbers doesn't matter. This is 18,564 groups of 6. Then, I find the combination of these dice using:

```
for j in itertools.combinations(W, 3):
    check = list(itertools.chain(*list(itertools.chain(*j))))
    check = sorted(check)
#print(check)
if check == num:
```

The issue arises from the fact that the second combination will iterate through 10^15 possibilities where only a small fraction of that is what I want to generate.

Another question I have:

I'm pretty sure that the total ways to assign 18 things to 3 distinct groups of 6 where the order within the groups doesn't matter is given by: 18!/(6!)^3  ~ 17 million ways, which can be iterated through relatively quickly. Is this right? Is there a way to generate these ways iteratively without filtering through a much larger set of possibilities?

One last note:

What I'm doing is trying to generate all sets of non-transitive six sided dice where each face of each dice has a distinct number. I already have the code that can check a set and decide if it fits this condition and store the best result, i.e. the highest probability of a dice beating the next dice in the line.

```
 for k in itertools.permutations(j):
        B = k[0]
        G = k[1]
        R = k[2]

        b = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0

        for m in B:
            for n in G:
                if m > n:
                    b = b + 1
                else:
                    continue
        for m in G:
            for n in R:
                if m > n:
                    g = g + 1
                else:
                    continue
        for m in R:
            for n in B:
                if m > n:
                    r = r + 1
                else:
                    continue

        w = w + 1
        print(w)
        if b <= 18 or g <= 18 or r <= 18:
            continue
        else:
            if b >= blue and g >= green  and r >= red:
                Blue = B
                blue = b

                Green = G
                green = g

                Red = R
                red = r

                print(B)
                print(b/36)
                print(G)
                print(g/36)
                print(R)
                print(r/36)
                continue
            else:
                continue
else:
    continue
```

Comment: Is this the same idea [Partitions of Groups of Equal Size](https://jwood000.github.io/RcppAlgos/articles/GeneralCombinatorics.html#partitions-of-groups-of-equal-size-with-combogroups)?

Comment: Oh wow, this seems very promising, thank you. I tried for a long time to search this problem on this site and others, but its about finding the right key words. I will take a look at this, thanks. Also, can I easily implement this in python? I'm somewhat of a newb, especially when it comes to different languages and implementing libraries and such.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it appears that the OP is looking for [Partitions of Groups of Equal Size](https://jwood000.github.io/RcppAlgos/articles/GeneralCombinatorics.html#partitions-of-groups-of-equal-size-with-combogroups).

The code below is converted from the algorithm implemented in `C++` found here: https://github.com/jwood000/RcppAlgos/blob/master/src/ComboGroupsUtils.cpp **<sup>*</sup>**. I put the comment in a block of its own below, followed by the pythonized code (N.B. it is a direct translation and there is probably room for improvement).

> ******* Overview of the Crucial Part of the Algorithm *******
>
> ---
>
> `last1` is one plus the upper bound in the previous section, so to obtain the current current upper bound, we must first add the size of a section (i.e. `grpSize`) and subtract one. We can now compute the length we need to reset `v` by subtracting `idx1`. E.g.
>
> Given a portion of `v` with `grpSize = 4`, `idx1 = 9`, 6 groups (24 subjects) and base 0:
>
> ```
>          prev sections   bound (index = 8)
>              /  \        |
>        ............. 8 | 9 12 23 24 | 10 20 21 22 | 11 ... 
>                             |
>                           idx1 (equal to last1, in this case)
> ```
>
> Sort `v` past `idx1`:
>
> ```
>                  ... 8 | 9 12 10 11 | 13 14 15 16 | 17...
> ```
>
> Determine the index, `idx3`, such that `v[idx3]` > `v[idx1]`
>
> ```
>                  ... 8 | 9 12 10 11 | 13 14 15 16 | 17 ... 
>                             |          |
>                           idx1       idx3
> ```
>
> Swap `idx1` and `idx3`:
>
> ```
>                  ... 8 | 9 13 10 11 | 12 14 15 16 | 17...
> ```
>
> Move enough indices after `idx1` to fill that specific group:
>
> ```
>                  ... 8 | 9 13 __ __ | 10 11 12 14 | 15 16 ...
> ```
>
> Identify and move indices that are successively incrementing values of `v` past `idx1`:
>
> ```
>                  ... 8 | 9 13 14 15 | 10 11 12 16 | 17 ...
> ```
>
> The last two steps are accomplished with `std::rotate`. This completes the algorithm.

Here are some helpers functions:

```
def rotate(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]

def numGroupCombs(n, nGrps, grpSize):
    result = 1

    for i in range(n, nGrps, -1):
        result *= i

    result = int(result)
    myDiv = 1

    for i in range(2, grpSize + 1):
        myDiv *= i

    result /= myDiv**nGrps
    return int(result)
```

And here is the main generator (The rotate function was obtained from this answer [Python list rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9457864/4408538)):

```
def ComboGroups(v, nGrps, grpSize):

    if not isinstance(v, list):
        z = list(v)
    else:
        z = v.copy()

    for i in range(numGroupCombs(len(z), nGrps, grpSize)):
        yield z.copy()

        idx1 = (nGrps - 1) * grpSize - 1
        idx2 = len(z) - 1;
        last1 = (nGrps - 2) * grpSize + 1

        while (idx2 > idx1 and z[idx2] > z[idx1]):
            idx2 -= 1

        if (idx2 + 1) < len(z):
            if z[idx2 + 1] > z[idx1]:
                z[idx1], z[idx2 + 1] = z[idx2 + 1], z[idx1]
        else:
            while idx1 > 0:
                tipPnt = z[idx2]

                while (idx1 > last1 and tipPnt < z[idx1]):
                    idx1 -= 1

                if tipPnt > z[idx1]:
                    idx3 = idx1 + 1
                    z[idx3:] = sorted(z[idx3:])
                    xtr = last1 + grpSize - idx3

                    while z[idx3] < z[idx1]:
                        idx3 += 1

                    z[idx3], z[idx1] = z[idx1], z[idx3]
                    z[(idx1 + 1):(idx3 + xtr)] = rotate(z[(idx1 + 1):(idx3 + xtr)], idx3 - idx1)
                    break
                else:
                    idx1 -= 2
                    idx2 -= grpSize
                    last1 -= grpSize
```

And here is an example usage (https://ideone.com/kygF03):

```
import time

def example(z, nGrps, verbose = True):
    grpSize = int(len(z) / nGrps)

    if verbose:
        for a in ComboGroups(z, nGrps, grpSize):
            print([a[i:i + grpSize] for i in range(0, len(a), grpSize)])
    else:
        start = time.time()

        for a in ComboGroups(z, nGrps, grpSize):
            b = a

        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)

example(list(range(1, 9)), 2)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 6, 7, 8]]
[[1, 2, 3, 6], [4, 5, 7, 8]]
[[1, 2, 3, 7], [4, 5, 6, 8]]
[[1, 2, 3, 8], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
[[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 6, 7, 8]]
[[1, 2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7, 8]]
[[1, 2, 4, 7], [3, 5, 6, 8]]
[[1, 2, 4, 8], [3, 5, 6, 7]]
[[1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 7, 8]]
[[1, 2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6, 8]]
[[1, 2, 5, 8], [3, 4, 6, 7]]
[[1, 2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 8]]
[[1, 2, 6, 8], [3, 4, 5, 7]]
[[1, 2, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 6, 7, 8]]
[[1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 5, 7, 8]]
[[1, 3, 4, 7], [2, 5, 6, 8]]
[[1, 3, 4, 8], [2, 5, 6, 7]]
[[1, 3, 5, 6], [2, 4, 7, 8]]
[[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
[[1, 3, 5, 8], [2, 4, 6, 7]]
[[1, 3, 6, 7], [2, 4, 5, 8]]
[[1, 3, 6, 8], [2, 4, 5, 7]]
[[1, 3, 7, 8], [2, 4, 5, 6]]
[[1, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 7, 8]]
[[1, 4, 5, 7], [2, 3, 6, 8]]
[[1, 4, 5, 8], [2, 3, 6, 7]]
[[1, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 5, 8]]
[[1, 4, 6, 8], [2, 3, 5, 7]]
[[1, 4, 7, 8], [2, 3, 5, 6]]
[[1, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 8]]
[[1, 5, 6, 8], [2, 3, 4, 7]]
[[1, 5, 7, 8], [2, 3, 4, 6]]
[[1, 6, 7, 8], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

And for your example, the unoptimized implementation above can iterate through all `2,858,856` results in just over 4 seconds.

```
example(list(range(1, 19)), 3, False)
4.4308202266693115
```

For reference, the same algorithm in `C++` runs in about 0.12 seconds.

**<sup>*</sup>** I am the author of `RcppAlgos`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'm trying to understand how the algorithm works, and since you said that my example has ~2 million results I assumed it removed the permutations of the dice within a set. So I added a for loop to run through these for each set that the algorithm generated, but in my results I appeared to get 6 identical dice that were being generated. I'm not exactly sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: Nevermind, I just had some errors in my code, thank you so much for this response, it does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

First, take all the combinations of choosing 6 things from 18. These are your first dice. There are 18564 possibilities.

Then, take all the combinations of choosing 6 things from 12 remaining (924), similarly. This will give you a second die, given your first one.

Finally, the third die is just all the remaining numbers. That's 18564x924x1=17,153,136 possibilities.

But actually, wait. We don't care about the order of the three dice, either. So we can assume that "1" is on the first die. And then that the lowest number not on the first die, is on the second die. That's 6188x462x1=2,858,856 possibilities.

Here's some python code. It's not as fast as if you did the combinations yourself, but it should run fine.

And if you run this on real transitive dice, try removing the "unique" constraint! I'm curious if there are interesting dice with repeats.

```
import itertools
def iter_dice():
    nums = list(range(1,19))
    for first_die in itertools.combinations(nums[1:], 5):
        first_die = (1,) + first_die
        remaining = sorted(set(nums) - set(first_die))
        for second_die in itertools.combinations(remaining[1:], 5):
            second_die = (remaining[0],) + second_die
            third_die = sorted(set(remaining) - set(second_die))
            yield first_die, second_die, third_die
print(len(list(iter_dice())))
print(next(iter_dice()))
```