# Iterating over all possible ways of dividing 12 objects over 4 groups

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I am trying to find a way to iterate over all possible combinations of dividing 12 objects over equally sized 4 groups (order within the group doesn't matter, the order of the groups does matter).

I know the total amount of combinations is 369600 = 12! / (3!)^4, but I have no idea how I would go about iterating over all these different combinations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating all possible sets of 3 groups of 6 numbers chosen from the integers 1-18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272107/generating-all-possible-sets-of-3-groups-of-6-numbers-chosen-from-the-integers-1)

Answer (score 0):

You have objects as `O[0], ..., O[11]` and groups as `G[0], ..., G[3]` now you could assign objects to groups with steps like this:

1.Select 3 object for `G[0]` like this:

```
for(i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
     for(j = i+1 ; j<11 ; j++){
         for(k = j+1 ; k<12 ; k++){
              G[0] = {O[i] , O[j] , O[k]}
```

2.Create a new object list by removing the `O[i], O[j], O[k]` from the object list and do the same thing like the pseudo-code above for `G[1]`, I mean something like this:

```
for(l = 0 ; l<7 ; l++){
     for(m = l+1 ; m<8 ; m++){
         for(n = m+1 ; n<9 ; n++){
              G[1] = {O[l] , O[m] , O[n]}
```

3. Do the same thing as step 2 for `G[2]`
4. Assign the 3 remaining items to `G[3]`
5. Write out `G[1], G[2], G[3], G[4]`