# How to change numbers around in a list (python)

Tags: python, numbers

i have been working on this for 3 hours now but i have no clue how to do it

can anyone help me with this?

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

temp = values[0]

for index in range (len(values) -1):
    values[index] = values [index]

values[len(values)-1] = temp
print values
```

i want the printed values to be in order as [2,3,4,5,1]
by simply changing those in the brackets

Comment: Lists have some useful methods: `values.append(values.pop(0))`

Comment: I solved it by myself thanx everyone tho!                                           values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


temp = values[0]

for index in range (len(values) -1):
    values[index] = values [index+1]

values[len(values)-1] = temp
print values

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to shift a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python)

Comment: more duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457832/python-list-rotation  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212025/moving-values-but-preserving-order-in-a-python-list

Answer (score 3):

[deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is more efficient way to do

```
In [1]: import collections

In [3]: dq = collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5])

In [4]: dq.rotate(-1)

In [5]: dq
Out[5]: deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
```

Comment: Nevertheless, it is more efficient and moreover it will work well with any iterables

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not available in the python libraries but you can leverage slicing to rotate list

### Implementation

```
def rotate(seq, n = 1, direc = 'l'):
    if direc.lower() == 'l':
        seq = seq[n:] + seq[0:n]
    else:
        seq = seq[-n:] + seq[:-n]
    return seq
```

### Demonstration

```
>>> rotate(values)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
>>> rotate(values,2,'l')
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
>>> rotate(values,2,'r')
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple but powerful slice syntax:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
shifted = values[1:]+values[:1]
assert shifted == [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about time one-liner, in the spirit of sleepsort:

```
while values != [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]: random.shuffle(values)
```